# Server-client communication packet content strategy

Tags: java, networking, protocols, communication

I'm trying to think in the best way on communication for the game I'm writing. The scenario is simple: tcp sockets and request for authentication, map updates, chat updates, etc. What I was thinking to use was set of classes, like User, Map, Creature, etc and have a Message class, which will have enum with message types and Object to store previously mentioned classes. After I will convert this with GSON to json and on other side I will decode it corresponding to the message type indicated by the element of enum. The problem is that I will pass sometimes too much unnecessary data and that's doesn't let me quiet plus the integration of new types of messages will not be very easy neither for me, nor for someone else who might use it. In the previous version I have used my own XML protocol which also doesn't let me very happy.
So what I'm asking is advice for me the better way for communication or maybe some improvement of my idea.

Thanks in advance,
Serhiy.

Comment: Won't simply use Strings like (for a tchat message) "m 9334 message content", with "m" telling it's a message and "9334" the ID of the player who spoke, do the trick ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XML and JSOn are intended to make application integration simple, but still be human readable.

If you want a protocol tuned to your needs, I suggest you start by determining what information you want to send and how it would look.  Document this before you even start implementing it.  That way the data sent will suit your needs. (This is more work BTW which is why it is not done more often)

Comment: But still simple String protocol is better then XML or JSON based protocol?

Comment: It can be better and I use them myself. But having to design the protocol is more work than not having to think about it. ;)

Comment: OK, thanks for your help, going to work on protocol design ;)